How can I call powershell.exe via Start-Process, to then call a script with its own parameters and capture the exit code?
I can't figure out the syntax for this, I have a config script that needs to be called from another script. When I call the config script manually, it looks like this config.ps1 -val1 "1234" -val2 "12.089" . I need to use Start-Process to call config.ps1 with the parameters as well as to not open a new window (non interactive) and to capture the exit code of config.ps1 and wait for it to return an exit code before proceeding further.
Here is what I've tried most recently
$process = Start-Process powershell.exe -FilePath "c:\config.ps1" -ArgumentList -val1 "1234" -val2 "12.089" -PassThru -WindowStyle Hidden -Wait;


why not just $process = c:\config.ps1 -val1 "1234" -val2 "12.089"?

Also, if you are starting in pwsh.exe and really need to run in ps v5 you can do $process = powershell.exe -NoProfile c:\config.ps1 -val1 "1234" -val2 "12.089"

That worked but did not capture the exit code. Afterwards, I set $LASTEXITCODE = 9999999 right before calling your code and then looked at $LASTEXITCODE after using your code and I was able to capture the exit code that way. Thank you for the help, if you want to propose an answer and add the $LASTEXITCODE part, I will accept it.

if you want $LASTEXITCODE from invoked script to be available in calling session you can use the call operator &, e.g. & c:\config.ps1 -val1 "12341234" -val2 "12.089"

If the answer is lacking from your perspective, please provide feedback. Your question exhibits both an obvious misconception as well as implied ones, all of which are worth addressing. Thus, an acknowledged answer would benefit future readers. If you're holding back because @Daniel provided helpful pointers but didn't post an answer, note that the use of -File, as discussed in the answer, is the crucial aspect needed for faithful exit-code reporting, which isn't addressed in these comments. @Daniel: If you feel something hasn't been addressed and you want to post your own answer, go ahead.

No @mklement0, nothing further from me.  I don't measure anywhere close to you and the the others.  I will crawl back to my hole and be dormant :)

, @Daniel, but don't sell yourself short: I've seen you post helpful comments many times. If the situation warrants, I encourage you to flesh them out into full answers. In the absence of other answers, even an answer that falls a bit short  - while acknowledging its limitations - is preferable to having no answer at all. If an answer is close enough in the eyes of others, their comments may help you get to providing a complete answer.


Building on Daniel's helpful comments.
The problem with your code:

$process = Start-Process powershell.exe -FilePath "c:\config.ps1" -ArgumentList -val1 "1234" -val2 "12.089" -PassThru -WindowStyle Hidden -Wait


You're invoking powershell.exe, which therefore needs to be the argument passed to Start-Process's -FilePath parameter.

Everything else - both the target PowerShell script, c:\config.ps1 and its arguments - must be passed to the -ArgumentList parameter, which is best done in the form of a single string with embedded quoting, if necessary.[1]


Thus, the immediate fix is (-WindowStyle Hidden omitted for  brevity; note the addition of -File and the use of a verbatim here-string (@'<newline>...<newline>'@) to simplify embedded quoting):
$process = 
  Start-Process -PassThru -Wait -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList @'
   -File "c:\config.ps1" -val1 "1234" -val2 "12.089"
'@

Note that while in this particular case omitting the -File parameter of powershell.exe, the Windows PowerShell CLI, would have worked in principle too - in which case -Command is implied, there is an important difference:

Only -File passes a script file's exit code through as the exit code of the powershell.exe process, whereas -Command reports only an abstract exit code: any nonzero exit code is mapped onto 1.[2]
Additionally, arguments are parsed differently between -File and -Command.[3]

$process.ExitCode then reflects the script's exit code.

Taking a step back:

Normally, you'd invoke a PowerShell script (*.ps1 file) in-process, by direct invocation, which is invariably synchronous (i.e., PowerShell waits for the script to terminate before continuing):
# Direct, in-process invocation.
# * If the script path must be quoted or is stored in a variable,
#   use &, the call operator (e.g., & "c:\config.ps1" ...)
# * If the script uses `exit` with a number to set an exit code, that
#   it will be reflected in $LASTEXITCODE.
c:\config.ps1 -val1 1234 -val2 12.089


If you do need process isolation or if you must make a cross-edition call, e.g., calling powershell.exe, the Windows PowerShell CLI, from a PowerShell (Core) 7 session, using direct invocation for the CLI call too is the simpler solution for a synchronous call, which too allows you to query the exit code via the automatic $LASTEXITCODE variable.
powershell.exe -File c:\config.ps1 -val1 1234 -val2 12.089



Note:

Your Start-Process call uses -WindowStyle Hidden and therefore hides any output produced by the script; if you similarly want to hide all output in direct invocation, append *>$null to the commands above.

Conversely, the direct-invocation technique allows you to capture the command's output, e.g.
$output = powershell.exe -File c:\config.ps1 -val1 1234 -val2 12.089

Curiously and unfortunately, PowerShell reports all its output streams via stdout in a CLI call by default;[4] however, if you use a 2> redirection, you can selectively capture error output in a file.




[1] See this answer for more information.
[2] See this answer for more information.
[3] See this answer for more information.
[4] See GitHub issue #7989 for a discussion of this problematic behavior.
